# Energy eigenvalues for $V(x,y,z)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

> We are to find energy eigenstate for potential $$V(x,y,z) = \alpha(x^2 + y^2 + 2\lambda xy) + \beta(z^2 + 2\epsilon z)   ,$$ where $\alpha, \beta > 0, |\lambda| < 1$ and $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.

My attempt:
I tried writing the potential in spherical coordinates hoping for it to come out to be a central potential but after calculation
\begin{equation}
V(r, \theta, \phi) = \alpha r^2\sin^2\theta(\cos\phi + sin\phi)^2 + \beta r\cos\theta(r\cos\theta + 2\epsilon)
\end{equation}
I dont think solving it this way would help. Any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be much easier in Cartesian coordinates. You should be able to use the method of separation of variables. It's easy to see that the $z$ variable is separate already. We left with $x$ and $y$ between which there is a coupling $xy$. You can make a perfect square here
$$x^2+y^2+2\lambda xy=\begin{bmatrix}x &y \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1& \lambda\\ \lambda &1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$$
You can diagonalize this matrix to make the change of variables in which there is no coupling.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the variable into $(x,y)$ plane and $z$ direction since these are not coupled. The $z$ part is simple since it's a displaced harmonic oscillator. The $(x,y)$ plane, depending on $\lambda$, can be diagonalized as harmonic oscillator or saddle or inverted harmonic oscillator.